# caching the form values

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have a search form.When user post the search form i take the user to the result page which has results of the search.Now if the user click on the back button of the browser ,i want that he should go to the search page form filled with his values.I am using java

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about web pages.  Are you sure you're using Java, and not the similarly named but otherwise-very-different language JavaScript?  I see that you tagged your question `jq`; does that stand for jQuery?

Comment: That's already the way that browsers work. If you hit the back button, you'll be brought back to the search form with the values you entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookies.

when the user submits, just store a json or other simple serialized string needed to configure your search form.

Then on the search form page build out, just check for the existence of the cookie, if no cookie, no value, etc.